# How do i get rid of those deformities in the shading?

Tags: modeling

i tried to use subsurf in this object and then use edge loops to keep the corners of those windows sharp. but that resulted in weird shading issues near the corners. any idea what can i do to fix this?
i have this link here i hope the issue is seen clear enough.
https://youtu.be/ZAkJh8MS10Q

and i add an image here so you can see the wireframe.
[image]

I will be very much gratefull for any help you can give.

Comment: I think we'd need to see the Blend file to see exactly what's going on as that image is somewhat distorted and not very clear as it's taken in viewport shading mode. Share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there.

Comment: very well. i am uploading the file here.
keep in mind i had changed the topology sense the post. with no backup i had to work on it to restore the topology you see in the screen shot so it may not be 100% identical

https://we.tl/t-uoCUuMgCMH.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark edges with a crease in the 3-D viewport properties panel, and then tell subdivision to not smooth those areas. Try that with the edges of the window.

As a matter fact, it looks like you’ve got the whole thing set to shade smooth, so you should probably turn on auto smooth in the mesh properties, and mark those edges as sharp as well.

Comment: Hey Thanls for the Reply!

its already set to shade smooth. as for the creasing, are you sure? because i had being thought that can lead to a bad topology once sub surfing.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the exact result you want, but this is a quick view of one I did from scratch:
[image]

I've only added creases to the centre window surround. The object was created from a cylinder with the cutouts made from deleted faces. I then added and applied a Solidify modifier, bevelled the inner edges of the frames and added the Subsurf modifier. The Blend file is here:
[image]

Comment: well i do want to keep the edges of the side menu sharp as well.

also. may i ask what is the bevel of the inner edges for?

Comment: Just apply the creases to the side widows as well in that case. I just left them clear to show what it looked like without them. The same applies to the bevels. - It looked as if the edges might be bevelled in your original image but there's no need for them if you want the corners sharp.

Comment: Ok so i was trying to recreate your work. overall its looks great but there is some weird distortion next to the corners.
https://youtu.be/8TJjcUnBggo

also i don't want the edges to be unrealistically sharp. i tried to overall bevel to the windows but it ended with more issues. any ideas as for what to do?

Comment: Try creating it without any bevels. If you select the edges which are too sharp, then open the 'N' panel Item tab, you can reduce  the Edges Data: Mean Crease amount to reduce the sharpness.

Comment: Ok so i got it work! i kind of cheated my way out by using the data transfomer modifier. but it seemed to do the trick.